# Function with array and prototype javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object, prototype

I got to do a program that shows how many 'men' do I have on my 'group' array. I got this so far:

```
Person.prototype.myFunction= function(group){
    if (this.gender = 'male') {
        console.log(group);
    }
    else{
        return Person;
    }
};

var person1 = new Person('Alex', 'male', '25');
var person2 = new Person('Roberto', 'male', '70');
var person3 = new Person('Silverio', 'male', '45');
var person4 = new Person('Arturo', 'male', '24');
var person5 = new Person('Ramón', 'male', '50');
var person6 = new Person('Sol', 'female', '25');
var person7 = new Person('Sarai', 'female', '20');
var person8 = new Person('Alexa', 'female', '22');
var person9 = new Person('Betty', 'female', '24');
var person10 = new Person('Daniela', 'female', '25');

var group=[person1, person2, person3, person4, person5, person6, person7, person8, person9, person10];
```

I'm sure that I'm close, but my if it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to iterate the group, and add one to `result` if the current person is male:

```js
var group = [
  new Person('Alex', 'male', '25'),
  new Person('Roberto', 'male', '70'),
  new Person('Silverio', 'male', '45'),
  new Person('Arturo', 'male', '24'),
  new Person('Ramón', 'male', '50'),
  new Person('Sol', 'female', '25'),
  new Person('Sarai', 'female', '20'),
  new Person('Alexa', 'female', '22'),
  new Person('Betty', 'female', '24'),
  new Person('Daniela', 'female', '25')
];

function countMales(group){
  var result = 0;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
    if(group[i].gender === 'male') result += 1;
  }
  
  return result;
};

console.log(countMales(group));

function Person(name, gender, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.age = age;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the function `reduce` you can accumulate the matches with `gender === 'male'`

**ES6 approach:**

```js
function Person(name, gender, age) {  this.name = name;  this.gender = gender;  this.age = age;}var person1 = new Person('Alex', 'male', '25');var person2 = new Person('Roberto', 'male', '70');var person3 = new Person('Silverio', 'male', '45');var person4 = new Person('Arturo', 'male', '24');var person5 = new Person('Ramón', 'male', '50');var person6 = new Person('Sol', 'female', '25');var person7 = new Person('Sarai', 'female', '20');var person8 = new Person('Alexa', 'female', '22');var person9 = new Person('Betty', 'female', '24');var person10 = new Person('Daniela', 'female', '25');var group=[person1, person2, person3, person4, person5, person6, person7, person8, person9, person10];

var howMany = group.reduce((a, {gender}) => (a + (gender === 'male')), 0);
console.log(howMany);
```

**Wider compatible approach using simple `for-of-loop`**

```js
function Person(name, gender, age) {  this.name = name;  this.gender = gender;  this.age = age;}var person1 = new Person('Alex', 'male', '25');var person2 = new Person('Roberto', 'male', '70');var person3 = new Person('Silverio', 'male', '45');var person4 = new Person('Arturo', 'male', '24');var person5 = new Person('Ramón', 'male', '50');var person6 = new Person('Sol', 'female', '25');var person7 = new Person('Sarai', 'female', '20');var person8 = new Person('Alexa', 'female', '22');var person9 = new Person('Betty', 'female', '24');var person10 = new Person('Daniela', 'female', '25');var group=[person1, person2, person3, person4, person5, person6, person7, person8, person9, person10];

var howMany = 0;
for (let person of group) {
  if (person.gender === 'male') howMany++;
}

console.log(howMany);
```

Comment: `reduce`, arrow functions and boolean casting into integers for the clearly newbie OP. At least explain what each does :D

Comment: ... destructuring too.